# SQL Server full text search not returning correct number rows

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, full-text-search

I have strange problem. Table has a computed column with full text search in this column.

When I using query:

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM Table 
 WHERE CONTAINS (ComputedColumn, 'David')

 2 rows returned.
```

And when using:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table 
WHERE ComputedColumn LIKE N'%David%'    

3 rows returned.
```

All three rows are identical.

Why? What is the problem? Maybe SQL Server has patch?

Comment: Have a look at this: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7510646/like-vs-contains-on-sql-server)

Comment: Thanks. But this link about who is faster. I'm interested where discard 1 row and what doing that CONTAIN return all 3 rows.

Comment: You know that the both have a different function right? so the both filter differently

Comment: I know but I have problem and I want solution. Its Happened in server with WINDOWS SERVER 2008R2 with SQL Server 2012. When I take backup and moved to the server Windows server 2012 with SQL Server 2014 it begin work fine.

Comment: Is it solution to solve this problem? without upgrade windows and sql server? and without change query?

Comment: I think you will have to d either the one or the other to fix the issue

Comment: I rebuild Full text search catalog and all works fine !!!