# In SQL Server 2012 does a wildcard search of '%text%' use the index?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2012-express

In SQL Server 2012 does a wildcard search of '%text%' use the index? I read that in MySQL it doesn't.

Comment: No, SQL Server **cannot** use any index if you search with a leading `%` and the `LIKE` operator. SQL Server will always have to do a full-table scan (or clustered index scan)

Comment: @marc_s of course [contains](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7510646/like-vs-contains-on-sql-server) is a different story

Comment: @ConradFrix: yes, absolutely - that's a word-based full-text search which has entirely different rules

Comment: It would be quicker to look at the query execution plan and that will tell you what it's going to do