# How to search Windows Search Indexed in file

Tags: powershell, windows-search

I have files indexed by the Windows Search service. I need function, which can find some string in text files. I have script in PowerShell, but it didn't work fine.

```
function search {
    param($path, $word)

    $c = $path + "\%"
    $query = "SELECT
        System.ItemName, System.ItemPathDisplay
    FROM SystemIndex
    WHERE System.ItemPathDisplay LIKE '$c' AND CONTAINS('$word')"

    $ADOCommand = New-Object -ComObject ADODB.Command
    $ADOConnection = New-Object -ComObject ADODB.Connection
    $RecordSet = New-Object -ComObject ADODB.RecordSet
    $ADOConnection.Open("Provider=Search.CollatorDSO;Extended Properties='Application=Windows';")

    $RecordSet.Open($query, $ADOConnection) 
    try { $RecordSet.MoveFirst() }
    catch [System.Exception] { "no records returned" }
    while (-not($RecordSet.EOF)) {
        if ($locatedFile) { Remove-Variable locatedFile }
        $locatedFile = New-Object -TypeName PSObject
        Add-Member -InputObject $locatedFile -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'Name' -Value ($RecordSet.Fields.Item("System.ItemName")).Value
        Add-Member -InputObject $locatedFile -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'Path' -Value ($RecordSet.Fields.Item("System.ItemPathDisplay")).Value
        $locatedFile
        $RecordSet.MoveNext()
    }

    $RecordSet.Close()
    $ADOConnection.Close()
    $RecordSet = $null
    $ADOConnection = $null
    [gc]::Collect()  
}
```

If `$word = "Hello"` it works fine for files where we have

```
*some text *      Hello     * some text*
```

in the file, but not when we have Hello without spaces like:

```
HelloWorld
```

We can't also search when `$word` is a phrase,for example "Hello World".

Anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is with the `CONTAINS` in your query. You should add asterisk (*) wildcard character to the word that you search. 
So instead of:

```
 WHERE System.ItemPathDisplay LIKE '$c' AND CONTAINS('$word')
```

please try:

```
WHERE System.ItemPathDisplay LIKE '$c' AND CONTAINS('*$word*')
```

Comment: I don't know why, but not working... Effect is the same

Comment: Please try using quotations around this $word$ as in this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33780775/5622042)

Comment: Still not working. I think that only way to do that is

Comment: Still not working. I think that only way to do that is  good $word variable like that :$word = "`"  *hello*`""