# MS SQL Contains with blank spaces between words

Tags: sql, sql-server, full-text-search, full-text-indexing

I have the following ms sql syntax to find all rows, which have these words:

```
select * from Expat_MA where CONTAINS (zusammen,'"*hans*" AND "*Level 4*"');
```

so this is my DB column, where the search is going through:

[image]

I just want the yellow marked row, but I get all 4 rows as result.

What's wrong ?

Comment: Do you have a full text index on the column? See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7510646/like-vs-contains-on-sql-server)

Comment: @Peter Smith: Yes i have a fulltext index on it

Comment: Then see some of the comments in the answer referenced above on the use of quotes and fuzzy matching.

Comment: Have you tried it without the wild cards? Is what you are searching for just `'hans AND "level 4"`?

Comment: Try `CONTAINS (zusammen,'"hans*" AND "Level 4*"')`

Answer (score 0):

I think the wild cards are giving false positives. Try the following:

```
select * from Expat_MA 
where CONTAINS (zusammen,'hans AND "Level 4"');
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this:

```
select * from Expat_MA 
where CONTAINS (zusammen,'"hans" AND "Level" AND "4"');
```