# How to select by a word in a row from a column which has an array inside?

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

I have a column that contains an array of strings. I try to select the items which have a certain word in that column but I get this error:

`function contains(character varying[], unknown) does not exist`

This is my select query:

```
SELECT "schedule", COUNT("schedule") AS "count" 
FROM "members" AS "member" 
WHERE contains("member"."facility_id", 'DEMO') 
GROUP BY "schedule";
```

Comment: Well, there is no function `contains()` in Postgres. What mad you think there is?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name this one:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7510646/like-vs-contains-on-sql-server, I have tried this one too but I got another error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14290857/sql-select-where-field-contains-words , so I searched on tried the other answer

Comment: Neither of those questions are for Postgres.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I thought they would work since both use SQL. :(

Comment: Both refer to a full text search in SQL Server, not for looking up elements in an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to test if an array of strings contains a specific element you need to use the contains [operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html) which is `@>` but only works with arrays on both sides

```
WHERE member.facility_id @> array['DEMO']
```

To test for a single value, you can also use the `any` operator:

```
WHERE 'DEMO' = ANY(member.facility_id)
```

Comment: Thank you! The second one has worked