# Sql Server CONTAINS function not works with some urls data

Tags: sql-server, contains

In my Sql Server database, I've a table containing an **nvarchar(4000)** field called **DataStructure**.
In this table I've 2 records having following data into DataStructure field:

```
Record 1:
{"FileName":"ACO23004000","SourceUrl":"http://mysite/TEST.TIF"}

Record 2:
{"FileName":"ACO23004000","SourceUrl":"http://mysite.fm/TEST.TIF"}
```

I try to search the value **ACO23004000** using the Contains command (full text search) in SqlServer as following:

```
Select *
from MyTable
where CONTAINS(DataStructure, '"*ACO23004000*"')
```

The query returns only the first record, seems that the ".fm" value into text prevents the search of the second record.

How can I solve this issue? Is possible that some characters prevent CONTAINS command to work correctly?

Comment: Full text search is for... texts, not jsons. Why not just do Select *
from MyTable
where DataStructure like '%ACO23004000%' ?

Comment: Note that the CONTAINS operator supports only search for prefixes not suffixes, as mentioned in the comments of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33780775/12492890) answer. Check that thread, maybe could be of some help to the specific full-text search use case.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to apply a condition on a json-formatted textual field. Use instead the [`OPENJSON`](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) operator to scrape it, and impose the corresponding condition on the filename.

```
SELECT MyTable.*
FROM MyTable
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(DataStructure) WITH(FileName VARCHAR(20) '$.FileName')
WHERE FileName = 'ACO23004000'
```

Output:

| DataStructure |
| --- |
| {"FileName":"ACO23004000","SourceUrl":"http://mysite/TEST.TIF"} |
| {"FileName":"ACO23004000","SourceUrl":"http://mysite.fm/TEST.TIF"} |

Check the demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/HwVO2JhP).

Note: You can define your best suitable type for "*SourceUrl*" field in the corresponding `WITH` clause of the `OPENJSON` operator, according to the nature of that field.

Comment: Hi @lemon, my situation was semplified for simplicity in my question but is a little more complex.
We use this query on a table containing (actually) 85.000.000 of rows and json structure can be different in all rows.
So what we need is a CONTAINS function that uses a full text index to get data. In that way, our query is executed in less than 1 second.
The OPENJSON command is very useful but not in our situation where we need something similar to a LIKE command (but faster, like CONTAINS with fulltext index)